# Next.js 13 how to revalidate client-side fetch from server side? (cookies-related)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I moved my app from next12 to next13. Some parts of my application depend on the server data, which is related to cookies changes. Specifically, I'm talking about the logged user data.

Right now I fetch everything (page data and user data) on page generation (preload pattern). But I have a big part of my app (for example, navbar) that depends ONLY on user data, so I don't see the necessity to fetch user on every page load.

The purpose is to prevent the navbar rerenders when the user is the same. Then instantly revalidate my navbar when the user changes (login) or is invalid (user logged out from another tab).

My idea is to fetch my user data on the client side. But then I need to revalidate it from server-side, here is the problem. Is there any way to initiate client fetches'`revalidateTag` from server-side?

My current pattern, where user data is loaded with page generation (`page.jsx=>PageContent.jsx`):

```
  return (
    <>
      <UserProvider initValue={user}>
        <Navbar />
        <PageDataProvider initValue={pageData}>


          <Main />

        </PageDataProvider>
      </UserProvider>
    </>
  );
```

My navbar gets user value from `React.Context`. I want to put the `Navbar` outside `page.jsx` level, `layout.jsx` would be the best. As user data changes independently from `pageData`, I don't think that providing user data based on page loads is a good idea.